# Table with fixed column and scroll

Tags: html, css

Im trying to do a table with fixed column and scrolls like the following link:
http://hazaa.com.au/blog/how-to-create-an-html-table-with-frozen-headers-and-columns/

Source code:https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=5e237543fffb2891&id=5E237543FFFB2891%21192

The point is that in this sample, the table have fixed width and heights in "px", and im needed that table fits according to the screen (replace the fixed "px" to "%").

Can someone help me on that? 
When i make the changes, i'm really can't bring up the vertical scroll!!

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you looked into the datatables.net library. I believe it will do everything you need and is very robust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a div inside the columns, text inside the div. Set `height:100%` on everything (especially html and body), `width: 100%` on the table and `overflow: auto` on the div

([Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/b12auzr1/))

```
html,body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
div {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```